# Juju Single still has a single master even HA is enabled

Tags: server, juju, maas, openstack

I'm install Juju on ubuntu 14.04 version 1.25
I notice i have 2 server first one is the master the second is the bootstrap node.

If i run command

```
juju ensure-availability -n 3
```

Juju will add 2 more machine to be a bootstrap. Now i notice that i have 3 bootstrap node as the document say.
**But** what if the master server fail ? because it look like Juju still have a single point of failure with the master server. Is there any implement for Juju Multiple master to increase the availability ?

Answer (score 0):

Though, I haven't used HA on 1.2X, Juju 2.0 has a lot of improvements. Juju 2.0 HA and backup features seems pretty solid.

Reference: 
- https://jujucharms.com/docs/2.0/controllers-ha
- https://jujucharms.com/docs/2.0/controllers-backup

Comment: No luck because enable-ha don't work with juju 2.0 on manual environtment. It need me to deploy the machine first but after deploy the machine come in the agent list not the controller list. Is there a way to add a mechine to controller list ?

Comment: agent list? do you mean, the controllers appear as machines in models instead of showing up in controllers list

Comment: Yeb i made the problem itself because i don't switch model to controller while adding the machine.. sorry about that